# Low Quality queue appears to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

After going to [the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) it loads and loads and loads and then shows an error.

Looking at my developer console it shows that `https://stackoverflow.com/review/next-task` is failing and forwarding to `error?aspxerrorpath=/review/next-task`.

It should be noted that this only seems to happen to me for this specific queue, the others are fine.

Chrome 31, Windows 7

Comment: repro-ed on IE11

Comment: Loads of things are b0rken atm.

Comment: hitting F5 100 times doesn't solve the problem for me... this time

Comment: I suspect that one machine in the cluster just went *boom*; some things are working, some things fell over. Like editing.

Comment: There is a general issue on [so] right now - we are working on it.

Comment: But, the hunger, must.... peer... review.

Comment: @Oded I hope it won't take six to eight weeks to fix

Comment: @JanDvorak - 6-8 minutes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a SQL issue just now where a cache bombed out and ran a metric shitload of queries trying to get something simple: a random selection of 3 of the top 30 tags to show when asking or editing a question.

I'm still not sure why this is an issue all of the sudden (hasn't changed in years), but it definitely just pegged out SQL server from 15% up to 100%.  A fix is building out now and a temporary fix (constant tags) was already deployed (which will be reverted).

Review queues have other issues, which I'll be tuning some today as well, but the SQL load greatly exacerbated the issue.