# Cannot edit posts on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, posts

When trying to edit post it loads and loads, but nothing happens. Looking at the *Developer Tools* of Chrome, I see a **500 Internal Server Error**.

Editing on Meta Stack Overflow is fine and works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Reproduced chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m.... I was about to report the same +1

Comment: Yup, [various](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216543) [things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216545) are b0rken at the moment.

Comment: We are working on your problems

Comment: Its working now

Comment: @Oded so it was you or Nick? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very unexpected SQL load issue related to loading the random sampling of tags we show in the editor was at fault here.  A different approach to gathering those tags is being deployed now.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67109/proposal-free-day-in-the-visit-log-to-account-for-the-oct-9th-downtime

Comment: @user248344 We were never offline, you only were blocked from editing or asking, and only for less than 7 minutes.