# The connection to wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/ was interrupted while loading the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, web-sockets

I get this error when trying to ask a question on stackoverflow.com
After a while, I get the following error page from StackOverflow.

[image]

Comment: As the error page tells you: the team has already been informed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Well: *It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, http://meta.stackoverflow.com.*

Comment: Yup, but what additional information did you give us? :-)

Comment: In any case, I see 2 other posts here on Meta for various problems, it appears the site is well broken in multiple locations.

Comment: We are working this - not isolated to wss.

Comment: @Oded - Solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow went belly up in a few areas for a moment due to a runaway process making our database server eat it pretty hard.  All is well now.