# The connection to wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/ was interrupted while the page was loading

Tags: support, firefox, web-sockets

On each page load SO gives me an error:

> The connection to wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/ was interrupted
>   while the page was loading.

Everything actually works and I can perform all actions normally - but I was just wondering why am I getting this error when I click on any link inside SO?

I've already read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216545/the-connection-to-wss-qa-sockets-stackexchange-com-was-interrupted-while-load), but I'm not experiencing the same behaviour - it just throws the connection error while everything works.

I use latest Firefox to browse SO.

I've tried:

- connecting to internet without router
- disabling Firefox live updates
- turning all plugins off
- turn off antivirus & firewall
- fresh install of Firefox

None of the above solved the problem.

Comment: Please visit this page and see if all is green: http://websocketstest.com/ if not, it's something on your end.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It is all green.

Comment: OK, what browser then? Do you have any browser plugins/extension enabled?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Added browser - latest firefox - only plugin instaled is Firebug (where I read the error).

Comment: Try to clear the cache and/or pressing CTRL+F5 - any luck?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nop - I actually just did a fresh instal of Firefox - first page I visited was SO - when I checked if Firebug works ok, I've notice it reporting this error.

Comment: I would go with yet another Firefox only weirdness then, we got a bunch already.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Probably - checked Chrome and IE - it does not throw this error.

Comment: Another direction: are you behind a proxy? Or using a router by any chance?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No proxy - but I do use a router.

Comment: Can you clear the router cache? Some routers might keep their own cache so who knows... :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can try - I can also try to plug the cable directly on the modem to bypass router - will report back in a sec.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Tried without router and it's the same.

Comment: Well, was worth a shot. Out of ideas, sorry!

Comment: @ShadowWizard No problem - I just cared to report the error - it does not prevent me from performing any action anyway. Maybe someone can replicate this.

Comment: Forgot to ask, do you have live updates?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes.

Comment: @easwee any updates? I am having same issue

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Help needed.

Comment: I can confirm that this is not an issue anymore using latest update of Firefox.